# Time Class Constructor

Tags: c++

Here is a implementation that I wrote to add hrs, min and sec in C++
Is there a way to implement this by converting all this to seconds and do a simpler implementation?
For some reason it wouldn't let me add the code in this post :(

Thank you

Comment: edit your post and try to add the code again

Comment: @Tony the crux of the code is here. I have the entire working code. I am just trying to get an idea about the seconds implementation of the same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement this by converting all this to seconds and do a simpler implementation?

Whichever way you go, you'll need to change the time between seconds and hour/minute/second quite often, so there's not necessarily a *huge* benefit to using one or the other for storage.  Put another way, seconds-since-midnight is probably nicer, but maybe not worth a rewrite.  For things like `+` and `-`, if you're not storing just seconds then you can calculate it easily (see Mark's post), do your arithmetic then have a function to convert from seconds back to hour/min/sec to store the result into your data members:

```
hours = seconds_since_midnight / 60 / 60;
minutes = seconds_since_midnight / 60 % 60;
seconds = seconds_since_midnight % 60;
```

Say you're adding 120 seconds to 23:59:00, you'll get a value past midnight, so you can use "total_seconds % 24 * 60 * 60" to get just the 60 seconds past the following midnight, equivalent to wrapping from "24:01:00" to 00:01:00.

(If you want to actually use this, and not just doing this to teach yourself, then consider using the `time()` function and associated conversion routines like `localtime()`)

Comment: what is "seconds-since-midnight"?

Comment: "seconds-since-midnight" is an alternative to storing hours/minutes and "seconds-since-the-minute-started".  Both use seconds, so I was saying "seconds since midnight" in an attempt to be extra clear!

Comment: Can you please give me an example for Seconds-since-Midnight? Thank you

Comment: For example lets say the user enters time1 - 12:12:12 and time2 - 2:2:2. So does that mean while adding I need to add time1 in seconds=43932 and time2 in seconds=7322. After addition. How do I convert them back to hh:mm:sec when displaying to user?

Comment: Yes for 43932 and 7322... they're seconds-since-midnight and magnitude sound about right. To get hh:mm:ss back, use the formulas already in my answer above, i.e. hh = 43932 / 60 / 60 = 12 (for an `int` type which rounds down - don't use `float` or `double`), mm = 43932 / 60 % 60 = 12, ss = 43932 % 60 = 12, so hh:mm:ss = 12:12:12.

Answer (score 3):

Converting hours, minutes, and seconds to just seconds is rather trivial:

```
total_seconds = hours*60*60 + minutes*60 + seconds;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark. But how is the implementation. Its is bit confusing for me to convert it to seconds and then add and then convert everything back to hr:min:sec?!